# Any events supported in ExcelDna?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I want to initialize a couple of variables on Excel Dna .dll gets loaded in the 
Excel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) will check whether your add has a public class that implements the interface `ExcelDna.Integration.IExcelAddIn`, and if so will run the AutoOpen method when the add-in is loaded, and the AutoClose method if the user removes the add-in from the add-ins list.

So you'd have something like:

```
public class MyAddIn : IExcelAddIn
{
    public void AutoOpen()
    {
        // Do your initialization here...
    }

    public void AutoClose()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Govert; Thanks for Update. This is certainly helpful. As I more look into ExcelDNA i am more enthused about that. I am planning to develop full fledge Add In which will have excel functions (i.e. UDF), custom task pane and custom ribbon. I will do all my coding in C# .dll;  I do not want to rely on .dna file; i will just ExternalLibrary Tag in .dna file. Can I put all of these features in one .dll ? As of now I have I have ExcelFunction (i.e. UDF)  within static class  which is working fine. Thanks for your help in advance...

Comment: You can do all of that in a single C# .dll, then pack everything into a single .xll file to give to your users.